# Microsoft Graph API - Upload file to one drive - Unable to read JSON request payload. Please ensure Content-T

Tags: php, graph, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am using the msgraph-sdk-php for uploading a file to a folder in One Drive. I have used composer on ubuntu to install the sdk.I am using PHP 7.4

I get the following error:

```
GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException 

  Client error: `PUT https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/10-01- 
  2021/children/invoices_10-01-2021.xlsx/content` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Unable to read JSON request payload. Please ensure Content-T (truncated...)

  at vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php:113
    109|         if ($summary !== null) {
    110|             $message .= ":\n{$summary}\n";
    111|         }
    112| 
  > 113|         return new $className($message, $request, $response, $previous, $handlerContext);
    114|     }
    115| 
    116|     /**
    117|      * Obfuscates URI if there is a username and a password present

      +12 vendor frames 
  13  app/Console/Commands/OneDriveSync.php:99
      Microsoft\Graph\Http\GraphRequest::upload()

      +13 vendor frames 
  27  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()


My code is as follows :

$files = glob('/home/ubuntu/*'.$now.'*');
foreach ($files as $fileName)
     {
             error_log($fileName);
             $filePart  = explode("/",$fileName);
             error_log($filePart[count($filePart) - 1]);


        $graph = new Graph();
        $graph->setAccessToken($accessToken);

        $response  =  $graph->createRequest("PUT", "/me/drive/root/"."2021-01-01". ."/children/".$filePart[count($filePart) - 1]."/content")
              ->upload($fileName);

              error_log($response->getStatus());
              error_log($response->getRawBody());
              if($response->getStatus() != 201)
              {
                   return;
              }

        unlink($fileName);
     }
```

I checked the SDK documentation and the file upload example is similar to what I have done.
I am able to create a new folder on one drive using POST command of the same SDK.
The file is existing on the path and is readable.I have checked that.

Kindly help.

Comment: See a similar post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51722614/microsoft-graph-unable-to-read-json-request-payload

Comment: The microsoft SDK documentation  and example does not mention attaching a JSON body to the PUT request. Infact the example clearly shows usage of the upload function for uploading the file.I also tried addHeaders function by changing the content type to text/plain.But it did not work.

Comment: Please try the call with the same data in POSTMAN and see if it works or not. Also use fiddler to check how the request body and the call hit the server so that you will get some insights.

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHP, but in general, you should have a `"Content-Type": "text/plain"` header in your `PUT` request and payload should be your file bytes encoded in base64, I'm using this API from Python (no SDK, direct HTTP request) and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Microsoft Graph API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content), you need to put a ':' at the end of the parent item (Folder) as well as the filename when you are uploading new files. I forgot to do that too and it resulted in the same error message.